# Getting the value of the Id Column in Tkinter Treeview

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, treeview, ttk

I would like to get the text of the Id column from a `Tkinter` treeview when I double click on a child node. Using `tree.identify_row(event.y)` I get the values of the other columns returned as a dictionary. I assume the Id is the key of that dictionary, but I can't figure out how to get it.

When I double click on subdir3, I would like to print `subdir3`, however, I only get `{'two': ' 3B', 'one': '3A'}`

```
from Tkinter import *
import ttk

root = Tk()

def OnDoubleClick(event):
    print tree.set(tree.identify_row(event.y))

tree = ttk.Treeview(root)

tree["columns"]=("one","two")
tree.heading("one", text="coulmn A")
tree.heading("two", text="column B")

tree.insert("", 3, "dir3", text="Dir 3",values=("3A"," 3B"))
tree.insert("dir3", 3, 'subdir3', text="sub dir 3",values=("3A"," 3B"))

tree.bind("<Double-1>", OnDoubleClick)


tree.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `print tree.identify_row(event.y)` works on my computer. The third argument of `tree.insert` is the iid.

Comment: I was also using the `set function`. Please submit as an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print tree.identify_row(event.y)
```

works on my computer. 
The third argument of `tree.insert` is the iid.